# Put controls on a form border in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, forms, user-interface, vb.net-2010, formborderstyle

I have a project where I want to put controls on the form's border, when the formborderstyle is set to `formborderstyle.sizable`

`Formborderstyle.none` will not work, since it can't be sized on runtime, and goes in front of the taskbar when maximized.

I'm using vb.net 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can override the drawing of the border and if you could not sure how you would add control to the border.

You can temporarily change the border style before you maximize the form. 
And you can overload the client event to handle re-sizing the form yourself.

Are there any other reasons you dont want to go with `Formborderstyle.none`?

```
Public Class Form1
Inherits Windows.Forms.Form

Private Const BorderWidth As Integer = 30 'This is just for demo purposes.

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Panel1.Location = New Point(Me.Width - BorderWidth, 0)
    Panel1.Width = BorderWidth
End Sub

Public xLocation, yLocation As Integer

Private Sub Panel1_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseDown
    xLocation = PointToScreen(Cursor.Position).X
    yLocation = PointToScreen(Cursor.Position).Y
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_MouseUp(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseUp
    'Stop resizing form
    Me.Width = Me.Width + (PointToScreen(Cursor.Position).X - xLocation)
    xLocation = PointToScreen(Cursor.Position).X
    yLocation = PointToScreen(Cursor.Position).Y
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Sorry about not being clear, I want to have a custom border style, but I want it to behave like `formborderstyle.sizable`, looks like the code works, though.